Throw-away return ticket and US immigration
Currently in the EU planning to go to the US on a one-way ticket. I'll be entering with a J-1 visa for a year-long stay.
Looking for tickets on a comparison website, the best pick ended up being a two-way flight, saying I should simply not board the return flight.
Morality of this practice aside, I'm wondering whether this could cause issues with the immigration officer when entering the country. Indeed, I'd be entering for long-term purposes, while having a return flight for a week later.

While it shouldn't be a problem, you can book the return leg which you are not planning to use for much, much later (depending on the airline, booking may be available up to around a year in advance). It may even be cheaper (though the price usually hits its lowest point pretty quickly), and if you select your date carefully you may even be able to use it (either at the end of your stay, or to come back home for a holiday or something like that).

Also, remember: it's usually best to book directly with the airline. That helps a lot if there are any disruptions/changes, it avoids the OTA and airlines pointing fingers to each other.

A return ticket should not cause issues, if it is not required by the visa.
But do not lie to the immigration officer: if asked talk about your plans to buy return ticket later. You can use it as plan-B if things go really wrong with your J-1 (but maybe you may need some more buffer weeks).
Note: when in US you may contact the issuer of the ticket about not being able to use it. Worst case nothing happen. Eventually you may get taxes refunded or also some credits for future: the airline has interest to know about passenger not flying: they may sell the ticket (so you may get some perks), OTOH they do not want people "abuse" the system to get lower prices (as you do). So you should phone (they use it as first screening). But no guarantee, and it seems it depends on the person on the other side.

you would think so, but logic doesn't apply to airline pricing anymore. Most will try to reprice the ticket and charge you a change fee on top of it. Of course, they have no easy way to enforce payment although sometimes they can.  I once had to pay $250 to NOT take a flight that I already had paid for. No refund, no credit, just a $250 fine. It's much safer just to be a no show without drawing attention to it.

@Hilmar: The fine are automatic, so things should not change, and you do not need to decide on the moment: I'm very sorry, but for reasons I may be forced to cancel the flight, what option do I have. Often it doesn't work, but I never got a fee, and sometime you get something back. -- but maybe it is a nice question, to see experience (which may change, and after COVID I have far less opportunities to flight, so things may have changed and I have not yet noticed).

If you call them and give them the heads up, you will always be able to recover the taxes, regardless of the airline policy or ticket restrictions
